# Tensorflow OSError: Unable to create link (name already exists), not able to save a simple model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Below is the code of my full model

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model, layers
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

GEN_FILTERS = 64

class Conv2D(layers.Conv2D):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size = 3, **kwargs):
        super(Conv2D, self).__init__(
            kernel_size = kernel_size,
            padding = 'same',
            **kwargs
        )

class ResidualDenseBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, out_filters = 64):
        super(ResidualDenseBlock, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = Conv2D(filters = out_filters / 2, activation = layers.LeakyReLU(0.2))
        self.conv2 = Conv2D(filters = out_filters / 2, activation = layers.LeakyReLU(0.2))
        self.conv3 = Conv2D(filters = out_filters, activation = layers.LeakyReLU(0.2))
        
        self.residual_beta = tf.Variable(1.0, trainable = True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x1 = self.conv1(inputs)
        x2 = self.conv2(tf.concat([inputs, x1], 3))
        x3 = self.conv3(tf.concat([inputs, x1, x2], 3))
        return x3 * self.residual_beta + inputs

class RRDBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, out_filters = 64, **kwargs):
        super(RRDBlock, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.rdb_1 = ResidualDenseBlock(out_filters)
        self.rdb_2 = ResidualDenseBlock(out_filters)
        self.rdb_3 = ResidualDenseBlock(out_filters)

        self.residual_beta = tf.Variable(1.0, trainable = True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x1 = self.rdb_1(inputs)
        x2 = self.rdb_2(x1)
        x3 = self.rdb_3(x2)
        return x3 * self.residual_beta + inputs

class PixelShuffleUpsampling(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, scale, **kwargs):
        super(PixelShuffleUpsampling, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.conv1 = Conv2D(filters = filters)
        self.upsample = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.nn.depth_to_space(x, scale))
        self.prelu = layers.PReLU(shared_axes = [1, 2])
    
    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.upsample(x)
        x = self.prelu(x)
        return x


lr_image = layers.Input(shape = (None, None, 3))

spatial_feats = layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255.0)(lr_image)
spatial_feats = Conv2D(filters = GEN_FILTERS, kernel_size = 9)(spatial_feats)

x = RRDBlock(GEN_FILTERS)(spatial_feats)
x = tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()(x)
rrdb_1 = layers.PReLU(shared_axes = [1, 2])(x)

x = layers.Add()([rrdb_1, spatial_feats])

x = RRDBlock(GEN_FILTERS)(x)
x = tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()(x)
rrdb_2 = layers.PReLU(shared_axes = [1, 2])(x)

x = layers.Add()([rrdb_2, rrdb_1])

x = RRDBlock(GEN_FILTERS)(x)
x = tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()(x)
rrdb_3 = layers.PReLU(shared_axes = [1, 2])(x)

x = layers.Add()([rrdb_3, rrdb_2])

x = RRDBlock(GEN_FILTERS)(x)
x = tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()(x)
rrdb_4 = layers.PReLU(shared_axes = [1, 2])(x)

x = layers.Add()([rrdb_4, rrdb_3])

x = Conv2D(filters = GEN_FILTERS)(x)
x = tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()(x)
x = layers.PReLU(shared_axes = [1, 2])(x)

x = Conv2D(filters = GEN_FILTERS)(x)
x = tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()(x)
x = layers.PReLU(shared_axes = [1, 2])(x)

x = PixelShuffleUpsampling(GEN_FILTERS * 4, 2)(x)
x = PixelShuffleUpsampling(GEN_FILTERS * 4, 2)(x)

x = Conv2D(filters = 3, kernel_size = 9, activation = 'tanh')(x)

sr_image = layers.Lambda(lambda x: (x + 1) * 127.5)(x)

generator = Model(inputs = lr_image, outputs = sr_image)
generator.summary()

generator.save_weights('generator.h5')
```

Running this is giving me the error on saving the model:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ....
  ....
    h5o.link(obj.id, self.id, name, lcpl=lcpl, lapl=self._lapl)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\h5o.pyx", line 202, in h5py.h5o.link
OSError: Unable to create link (name already exists)
```

Till the last day, everything was going smoothly, not sure at all where I screwed. Please help me out here. I tried removing all the names from the layers so that no two layers/parameters has the same name.
But still facing the same.

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: 2.4.1 it is, whch is installed by default on google colab as of now..o